# Un Expected Token error node JS

Tags: node.js

[Image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU4Jz.png)Here the Code, i am getting unexpected token error while running script

```
const WelcomeAsync = async () => {
    console.log('WelcomeAsync')

    if (state === STATE_GET_STARTED)
         return await GetStartedAsync()
    else {
        if (request.text.toLowerCase() === 'about')
            return await AboutAsync()
        else
            return [
                `Hi ${user.first_name}!`,
            ].concat(await HelpAsync())
    }
}
```

Link for Code: https://github.com/claudiajs/claudia-bot-builder/blob/master/lib/facebook/format-message.js

Comment: Where do you run it?
Maybe your environment doesn't support ES7?

Comment: getting error while deploying to AWS Lambda threw terminal

Comment: You do not just get an "unexpected token error". It usually tells you what *token* and on what *line* the error occurs.

Comment: Its getting Error async () here, sorry for that updating error point as well

Comment: It sure sounds like your environment does not support ES7 `async` and `await`.  Please edit your question to inlude the EXACT error message including which line of code it is complaining about - that information is key to explaining exactly what is going on and is always something you should be paying precise attention to.  The parser is telling you exactly where things went wrong and you/we should not have to guess about that.

Comment: @jfriend00 i checked ES7 is supporting and i am using bebel as well, i already uploaded image at point where error occurring please see image reference for type of error and point of error

Comment: If you're using Babel to compile for an ES6 target, then you are doing something wrong because there should be no `await` or `async` keywords in ES6 generated code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your reference for Claudia Bot Builder, I assume you're running your code in AWS Lambda. Lambda currently runs Node.js with 4.3.2 (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model.html), so those JavaScript features are not yet be available there. You can use transpilation with Babel or something similar to create a version compatible with Node 4.3. With Claudia, just use a post-install script in NPM to transpile JS.